# Bootstrap 3.0 menu not working on mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, navbar

I'm seeing an issue in bootstrap 3.0 that the navigation menu is not working when the menu is collapsed. To view an example please go here: http://apexenergetics.azurewebsites.net/

I'm starting to think perhaps I have a missing Javascript file or something. I've tested the website on my iPhone5 and also my iPad.  It's working fine when viewing in the browser.

UPDATE: It seems to be working fine on Windows Phones.  Also, only items with dropdowns do not work. Links/buttons without a drop down work.

```
<header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <img src="@Href("~/img/logo.png")" alt="Apex Energetics">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              @*<form class="form-search">
          <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search Apex Energetics">
          <button type="submit" class="search-btn" >Search</button>
            </form>*@
            </div>
        </div>

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Href("~/index")">Home</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Apex Complexes <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/K-Line_Formulas")">K-Line Formulas</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/K-plex")">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;K-Line Nutritionals</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/K-Line_Creams")">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;K-Line Creams</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/K-Line_Homeopathics")">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;K-Line Homeopathics</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/Z-plex")">TerrainZyme&reg; Formulas</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/L-plex")">Cellegion Formula&reg;</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Homeopathics <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/antitox")">Antitox&reg;</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/A-plex")">&nbsp;&nbsp;-B-Plex</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/B-plex")">&nbsp;&nbsp;-B-Plex</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/C-plex")">&nbsp;&nbsp;-C-Plex</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/D-plex")">&nbsp;&nbsp;-D-Plex</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/E-plex")">&nbsp;&nbsp;-E-Plex</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/N-plex")">&nbsp;&nbsp;-N-Plex</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/W-plex")">&nbsp;&nbsp;-W-Plex</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/S-plex")">Allertox</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/R-plex")">RegenRx</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/G-plex")">Metaboplex</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/M-plex")">Endotox</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="@Href("~/products/flowers")">Flower Combinations</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="@Href("~/products/purvela")">Purvela&trade;</a></li>
              <li><a href="@Href("~/pages/contact")">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. There is an issue where Bootstrap 3's dropdowns sometimes don't work on touch. If that's your issue, you can target your collapsed dropdown button for mobile only like this...

`if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i)) {}`

...and add separate functionality for dropdown on mobile.

Comment: I put this in a <script> tag on our base (index) page that contains the HTML for the navbar. Our base page is the base for every other page on the site, so the code is always present. Otherwise, import it from a separate .js file that is loaded on any page where the navbar is present.

Comment: I tested the above sample site on my Nexus 5 and it is working great.  My site however has the same problem as the OP mentions.  So has there later been a fix?